# Multiselect is not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I`m trying to pass related params into a model with multiselect list. I need to assing classes to lecturers by choosing a lector when creating new class entry. I checked the db and got nothing in lecturers_id column. This is my form:

```
     <%= f.select(:lecturers_id, Lecturer.all.collect {|l| [ l.name, l.id ] }, {}, { :multiple => true }) %>
```

My controller:

```
def subject_params
    params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :credit, :number_of_hours, :lecturers_id => [])
end
 def create
    @subject = Subject.new(subject_params)
    @subject.save
    redirect_to "/subjects" and return
end
```

And my view:

```
 <% @lecturers.each do |lect| %>
        <tr>
            <td class='col-md-3'><%= lect.name %></td>
            <td class='col-md-3'>
                <% lect.subjects do |subj| %>
                <%= subj.name %>
                <% end %>
            </td>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: What is `@subject.errors` after `@subject.save` is called?

Comment: @danielrsmith none. Saving is working normal

Comment: What is the association? A multi select field infers that subject has many lecturers, but you mention `lecturers_id` column. Is this a column on subjects table? if so then this is incorrect for as multi select field..

Comment: @jverban lecturer has many subjects

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the association is that `Subject` `has_many :lecturers` then you would change `lecturers_id` to `lecturers_ids`:

```
def subject_params
    params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :credit, :number_of_hours, :lecturers_ids => [])
end
```

Form:

```
<%= f.select(:lecturers_ids, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `Subject` `has_many :lecturers`. Your form should be

```
<%= f.select(:lecturer_ids, Lecturer.all.collect {|l| [ l.name, l.id ] }, {}, { :multiple => true }) %>
```

and your `subject_params` should be

```
def subject_params
    params.require(:subject).permit(:name, :credit, :number_of_hours, :lecturer_ids => [])
end
```